# How to feed install4j the key file password

Tags: gradle, install4j

I have self signed a certificate and I am trying signing the exe with Install4j. I have put a password on it which is 12345678. The key file seems to be found and yes it is encrypted (pw:12345678). The output is:

```
Loading config file C:\Users\alexa\IdeaProjects\downlords-faf-client\downlords-faf-client.install4j------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The private key is encrypted. To avoid manual intervention, set the
"--win-keystore-password" command line option or the 
"winKeystorePassword" gradle property or ant task attribute. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enter the password for the Windows key store:


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date
install4j: compilation failed. Reason: null
```

I have both tried to set the password in gradle.properties and via command line.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe key has the wrong format

Comment: Should be correct from what I found researching it. I generated a pfx file with Export-PfxCertificate .

Comment: Seems the certificate is broken in some way, just the message of Install4j is really confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a gradle property will not pass the value to the install4j compiler, you have to configure the property on the [gradle task](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/gradle.html).

The error message is misleading, it should say

> "winKeystorePassword" gradle task property

instead of

> "winKeystorePassword" gradle property

This will be fixed for 8.0.9.

Comment: Resulting changes I made: https://github.com/FAForever/downlords-faf-client/commit/7dabda385e858b65d9e02cb914aa72cb982c789f